# Merging several vcf files using snakemake

Tags: merge, snakemake, vcf-vcard

I am trying to merge several vcf files by chromosome using snakemake. My files are like this, and as you can see has various coordinates. What is the best way to merge all chr1A and all chr1B?

```
chr1A:0-2096.filtered.vcf
chr1A:2096-7896.filtered.vcf
chr1B:0-3456.filtered.vcf
chr1B:3456-8796.filtered.vcf
```

My pseudocode:

```
chromosomes=["chr1A","chr1B"]

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("{sample}.vcf", sample=chromosomes)

rule merge:
    input:
        I1="path/to/file/{sample}.xxx.filtered.vcf",
        I2="path/to/file/{sample}.xxx.filtered.vcf",
    output:
        outf ="{sample}.vcf"
    shell:
        """
        java -jar picard.jar GatherVcfs I={input.I1} I={input.I2} O={output.outf}
        """
```

EDIT:

```
workdir: "/media/prova/Maxtor2/vcf2/merged/"

import subprocess

d = {"chr1A": ["chr1A:0-2096.flanking.view.filtered.vcf", "chr1A:2096-7896.flanking.view.filtered.vcf"],
     "chr1B": ["chr1B:0-3456.flanking.view.filtered.vcf", "chr1B:3456-8796.flanking.view.filtered.vcf"]}


rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.vcf", sample=d)

def f(w):
    return d.get(w.chromosome, "")


rule merge:
    input:
        f
    output:
        outf ="{chromosome}.vcf"
    params:
        lambda w: "I=" + " I=".join(d[w.chromosome])
    shell:
        "java -jar /home/Documents/Tools/picard.jar GatherVcfs {params[0]} O={output.outf}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your bug. When constraining the wildcards, it works:

```
d = {"chr1A": ["chr1A:0-2096.flanking.view.filtered.vcf", "chr1A:2096-7896.flanking.view.filtered.vcf"],
     "chr1B": ["chr1B:0-3456.flanking.view.filtered.vcf", "chr1B:3456-8796.flanking.view.filtered.vcf"]}

chromosomes = list(d)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.vcf", sample=chromosomes)

# these tell Snakemake exactly what values the wildcards may take
# we use "|" to create the regex chr1A|chr1B
wildcard_constraints:
    chromosome = "|".join(chromosomes)

rule merge:
    input:
        # a lambda is an unnamed function
        # the first argument is the wildcards
        # we merely use it to look up the appropriate files in the dict d
        lambda w: d[w.chromosome]
    output:
        outf = "{chromosome}.vcf"
    params:
        # here we create the string 
        # "I=chr1A:0-2096.flanking.view.filtered.vcf I=chr1A:2096-7896.flanking.view.filtered.vcf"
        # for use in our command
        lambda w: "I=" + " I=".join(d[w.chromosome])
    shell:
        "java -jar /home/Documents/Tools/picard.jar GatherVcfs {params[0]} O={output.outf}"
```

It should have worked without the constraints too; this seems like a bug in Snakemake.

Comment: hi, this is giving me the following error: KeyError: 'chr1A:0-2096.filtered'

Comment: actually, I am using exactly your code :) I just added chr1A because my files are called chr1A:0-2096.filtered.vcf (but even if I delete chr1A the error remains) and I just added all other chromosomes...see the EDIT above

Comment: Actually, it says: InputFunctionException in line 35, where there is input: f.

Comment: I don't know since I dont understand 80% of the code I am confused...so sorry...if I indent print(w) it gives this: KeyError: '2096-7896.filtered'

Comment: if I put it right after def f(w) I get this: chr1B
chr1A
0-3456.filtered. And then InputFunctionException in line 16 Snakefile_merge:
KeyError: '0-3456.filtered'

Comment: Invalid syntax at wildcard_constraints: line... :( sorry may be something wrong with me snakemake?

Comment: Your version sounds ancient. Mine is 5.5.4

Comment: `pip install snakemake` or `conda install -c bioconda snakemake`

Comment: I closed the terminal and reopened it and now it is working...I have snakemake version 3.13.3...could you please add some comment lines to explain the code? because there are some scripting I am not familiar with.. thank you so much for your help and especially for patience..